# iMessage issue when being sent to cell number

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

A friend of mine has iPhone 4S with iOS 5.0. I can iMessage him using his apple id fine. However, when I try to use his cellphone number, I never get the light blue send button. It stays green all the time. This seems very strange to me. Any explanations?

Comment: Does your friend use a service like Google Voice?

Comment: Might it be that the cell number is forcing cellular texting and the Apple ID is allowing him to get the message via wifi if he's using a wifi network. Remember, iMessage is still in beta so this may not be the way it's going to work when released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iMessage sends a text message to get activated on the first boot of the phone. Maybe this text message didn't arrived at Apple, so that his iMessage is only activated for use with his Apple ID.

He could try to deactivate and reactive iMessage.

Comment: Deactivated iMessage. Restarted iphone. Activated iPhone and it worked liked a charm. Thanks Pre!